# Jquery click event work only when page to top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have CSS tabs:

```
.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
.tabs label {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 1px -1px 0;
    padding: 0 13px 1px;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F9F9;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs label:hover {
    color: #F70;
    padding: 0 13px;
    background: #FFFFDF;
    border: 1px solid #FFCA95;
}

.tabs input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

#tab_1:checked  ~ #tab_l1,
#tab_2:checked  ~ #tab_l2 {
    color: #444;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    padding: 0 13px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    z-index: 3
}

.tabs_cont {
    position: relative;
    height: 552px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-width: 1px;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    padding: 0 12px;
    z-index: 2; 
}

.tabs_cont > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
#tab_1:checked ~ .tabs_cont #tab_c1,
#tab_2:checked ~ .tabs_cont #tab_c2 {
    position: static;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and html:

```
<section class="tabs">
    <input id="tab_1" type="radio" name="tab" checked="checked" />
    <input id="tab_2" type="radio" name="tab" />

    <label for="tab_1" id="tab_l1">Изображения</label>
    <label for="tab_2" id="tab_l2">Текст</label>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div class="tabs_cont">
        <div id="tab_c1"> </div>
        <div id="tab_c2">
            <div class="add_element" id="add_text">добавить текст </div>
            <div id="text_inputs_wrapper"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And JS:

```
$("div#add_text").click(function ()  //on add input button click
{
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); 
});
```

When the page is in the upper position, the event is running. If I`m use scroll and page move - event is not running.
The problem occurs in all browsers.
Has anyone encountered this problem? Help please.

**UPDATE.**
Please see picture

1. in this case the event is running
   http://1drv.ms/1wg73ak
2. in this case the event is not running
   http://1drv.ms/1mt24JS

Comment: When you click inside this div z<div class="add_element" id="add_text">добавить текст </div>` it will work. regardless of scroll position. Obviously the div needs to be in sight in order to click it DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/cqgceq92/

Comment: I explained my question pictures. please take a look

Comment: It is not possible to diagnose the issue like this. Try the following in chrome: right click on the element, click inspect element and make sure `div#add_text` is selected in the inspector. If some other element is selected then it means the other element is covering the div, may be z-index or overflow issue.

Comment: The reason for this behavior is the library Fabric.js. When you remove this library events begin to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

As Vector said, you can only click on the #add_text div to trigger the event. The #add_text div is only has a height of one line so you have to click right on the text.

Add a height: 100% to your tab_c2 and to the #add_text then you can click anywhere on the 2nd tab page to trigger the event.

Comment: I explained my question pictures. please take a look

Comment: @sanyasobolev I understood your question and what is going wrong but what you are not explaining or understanding is that the div you have added the click event to is only about 15px in height. So when you scroll down your page a little bit that div is not clickable. Did you add the code above i suggested to expand the size of the div?

Comment: The reason for this behavior is the library Fabric.js. When you remove this library events begin to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Append this code to your css, your *div#add_text* will fill the entire container area and the click is works in all position

```
#add_text {
    background-color: red; //remove this later
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```